# How to stop timer in windows service so that code doesn't hit multiple times?

Tags: c#, timer, windows-services

**THIS IS SAMPLE CONSOLE APPLICATION NOT THE ORIGINAL WINDOWS SERVICE**

I have below code (sample code only). I want that my timer should execute only once and after that it should stop.

Currently I am using `count` field to check if the code is already hit or not. It is working fine but I want to optimize the things.

**NOTE :**
Reason behind using the timer is that during installation of windows service `OnStart` event shouldn't delay service installation process.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        static int count = 0;

        static void Main()
        {
            System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            timer.Elapsed += OnElapseTime;
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).TotalMilliseconds;
            timer.Start();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
            timer.Stop();
        }

        static void OnElapseTime(object sender,
                                          System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (count < 1)
            {
                count++;
                Console.WriteLine("Timer ticked...");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How to stop the timer so that ``OnElapseTime`` should not call anymore. it should be call only once

Comment: Why do you use a timer if it's only supposed to be executed once? Just execute a new thread or task.

Comment: @Bauss, OP wants to wait a while before executing the code.

Comment: `Task.Delay` anyone? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194873(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @bauss : ``Richard`` is right. Delay is necessary because I don't want any problem while starting windows service.

Comment: You can use `Task.Delay`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the [AutoReset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-s/library/system.timers.timer.autoreset(v=vs.110).aspx) to `false`.  This causes the event to be only fired once.  You can remove the code using `count`.

```
timer.AutoReset = false;
```

Comment: Thanks It was sweet and simple

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve what you want, which is essentially a delayed execution.

The simplest in terms of modifying what you have might be something like this:

```
static void Main()
{
   System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
   timer.Elapsed += OnElapseTime;
   timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).TotalMilliseconds;
   timer.Start();
}

static void OnElapseTime(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    var timer = (System.Timers.Timer)sender;
    timer.Stop();  // stop the timer after first run

    // do the work.. (be careful, this is running on a background thread)
    Console.WriteLine("Timer ticked...");
    Console.ReadLine();            
}
```

Antoher approcah might be to use the System.Threading.Timer class instead of the System.Timers.Timer and schedule a one time delayed execution:

```
static void Main()
{
   var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(RunDelayed, null, imeSpan.FromSeconds(5).TotalMilliseconds, Timeout.Infinite );
}

private void Callback( Object state )
{
    // do the work.. (be careful, this is running on a background thread)
    Console.WriteLine("Timer ticked...");
    Console.ReadLine(); 
}
```

Here is a good article that talks about differences between different timer classes available in .NET: https://web.archive.org/web/20150329101415/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx